# Firebase Query show key value if its true

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to console out `group2` members, so result should be `user2` in this case, and doesn't show if it doesn't exist:

```
{
  "users":{
    "user1":{
        "username":"john",
        "groups":{
            "group1":true,
            "group3":true
        }
    },
    "user2": ...,
  }
  "groups": {
     "group1"{
        ...
      },
     "group2"{
        "group_name":"Moderators",
        "members":{
            "user2":true
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

I've tried:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('groups');
            ref.orderByChild("user2").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                console.log(snapshot.key)
            });
```

but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to list the members of group 2:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('groups');
ref.child("group2/members").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key)
});
```

This will print:

> user2